# malloc: : pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++, xcode, malloc

```
class Solution {
    public:
    vector<vector<string>> partition(string s) {
        vector<string> res;
        vector<vector<string> > solution;
        int len = s.size();
        vector<vector<bool> > map(len+1, (vector<bool>(len+1,false)));
        if(len == 0) return solution;
        for(int i = len-1; i>=0; i--){
            for(int j = i; j<len; j++){
                if(s[i] == s[j] &&(j-i<2 || map[i-1][j-1])){
                    map[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        getSolution(res, solution, map, s, 0, len);
        return solution;
    }
    void getSolution(vector<string> &res, vector<vector<string> > &solution, vector<vector<bool> > map, string s, int st, int e){
        if(st >= e){
            solution.push_back(res);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = st; i<e; i++){
            string piece = s.substr(st, i-st+1);
            if(map[st][i]){
                res.push_back(piece);
                getSolution(res, solution, map, s, i+1, e);
            }
            res.pop_back();
        }
        return;
    }
};
```

I get this double free malloc problem. But I did not delete any memory here and I did not see auto free memory here? 
I set the break point and the problem prompts up when program goes to

```
return solution;
```

Comment: `getSolution` takes several arguments by value including `map` and is recursive, so quite possibly you're simply running out of memory (depending on how many levels of recursion and how big `map` is). By the way, it's a bad idea to use `map` as a variable name since it could conflict with the template class called `map` in the standard library.

Comment: 'res.pop_back();' is fishy in your recursive 'getSolution'

Comment: `vector<bool>` Isn't that a bit fishy  ??